# Make a new list from another list

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

I have a list like this:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {6, 8}, {9, 0}, {10, 11}, {12, 15}}
```

I use this code and make a new list.

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {6, 8}, {9, 0}, {10, 11}, {12, 15}};
data //. {a_, b_} :> {a}
```

that it gives:

```
{{1}, {3}, {6}, {9}, {10}, {12}}
```

now I want to calculate this:

```
3-1 = 2
6-3 = 3
9-6 = 3
10-9 = 1
12-10 = 2
```

and at the end make this list:

```
{2,3,3,1,2}
```

is it possible in Mathematica?

Comment: `Differences@alist[[All, 1]]` should do it, where `alist` is your input list. If there is a reason why you are taking the intermediate steps shown above, then please provide an explanation.

Comment: Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab first element, use Differences.

```
Differences[First /@ data]
```

Comment: Thank's for your correct answer. Thank you so much.